# With Heroku terminating their free dynos, what's the best alternative?

Tags: heroku, web-applications, cloud, free, dyno

Recently I was informed that Heroku will be terminating their free dynos which offered 1000 hrs/month to users with a registered credit card. Users will have to upgrade to the $7/m Hobbyist plan on the minimum before the 28th of November 2022 to continue with the service.

With this offer gone I was curious to know what the StackOverflow community thinks is a viable alternative to Heroku?

Comment: Please review what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend off-site resources, like hosting providers, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I faced the same problem and wrote an article that compares between three different options. I also moved to Render. You can read the article [here](https://medium.com/gitconnected/the-end-of-free-dynos-at-heroku-272fdf2d78c4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me Fly.io, render.com, Supabase (for postgres databses) just to name some alternatives. But Render would be the best choice in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you! Also just to help future readers with their search its: https://render.com/

Comment: do you know if there's a way to recover the database now that they're deleted? i have a free application for testing and as i understood, heroku staff themselves don't support recovering the database. i don't really care for the data, just curious.